# Waiting for function to finish - execution is asynchronous (not in order)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get user's city and country before moving on with my code. It seems as if javascript is not executed in the order I need.

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
  var country, city = '';

  function geoData() {
    $.getJSON('http://ipinfo.io/json?callback=?', function (data) { 
      console.log('step 1');
      country = data.country;
      city = data.city;
      console.log('step 2');
    });
  };

  geoData();        
  console.log('step 3');

  /* rest of the code */
});
```

I want the code to be executed as:

```
step 1
step 2
step 3
```

However when I run the script I get:

```
step 3
step 1
step 2
```

Why is the code running in an asynchronous way? Any suggestions how I can fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: Wait for the load to finish, and then run step 3.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

AJAX requests are asynchronous - it's what the first A stands for. If you have logic that depends on the data returned by the request, it needs to be placed within the callback function. Try this:

```
var country, city = '';

function geoData() {
    $.getJSON('http://ipinfo.io/json?callback=?', function (data) { 
        console.log('step 1');
        country = data.country;
        city = data.city;
        console.log('step 2');

        step3();
    });
};

function step3() {
    console.log('step 3');
}

geoData();
```

An alternative is to use a promise, although the logic flow is roughly equivalent:

```
var country, city = '';

function geoData() {
    return $.getJSON('http://ipinfo.io/json?callback=?', function (data) { 
        console.log('step 1');
        country = data.country;
        city = data.city;
        console.log('step 2');
    });
};

var deferred = geoData();
$.when(deferred).done(function() {
    console.log('step 3');
});
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you. I finally understand the logic.

Comment: It's so odd that I cannot get this to work at all.. No matter what the last function to be called overwrites data from the previous function.

Answer (score 3):

Use jQuery promises to get your desired result, like so:

```
var geoDataRequest = function () {

    var deferred = $.Deferred();

     $.getJSON('http://ipinfo.io/json?callback=?', function (data) { 
         deferred.resolve(data);
     });

    return deferred.promise();
};

var somefunction = function () {

    // This will return a promise
    var getGeoData = geoDataRequest ();

    // The appropriate function will be called based on if the promise is resolved or rejected through the success and error functions in the AJAX request
    getGeoData.then(

        // Done response
        function (result) {
            alert("Success! ");
            // Enter logic here for step 2 and 3
        },

        // Fail response
        function (xhr, status, errorThrown) {
            // Handle errors here...
        }
    );
};

somefunction();
```

In addition, you can now use your `geoDataRequest` whenever you like, and handle the results differently if you like!

Comment: I've tried this method I cannot get when, done, then to work. Deferred or promise just don't do anything.